# Store snprintf arguments for later use

Tags: c++, templates, printf, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I want my GUI application to print dynamic data on the screen (mouse coords etc.) through a user-defined format and using user-choosed variables. I need something like a class that stores this format (a `char*`) and all its variables pointers (`int*`, `char*`, `std::string*` etc.)

Let's say I want a tooltip balloon to display mouse coordinates. My class would be:

```
class Printer{
private:
char *format;
// std::vector with pointers? Variadic template?

public:
   Printer(char *format, ...){
      // code
   }
};
```

User would define a format with variables:

```
int x, y;
Printer p("X (%d), Y (%d)", &x, &y);
```

The mouse callback function would update `x` and `y` values.
And `Printer` would do:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, *variables);
```

After that, buffer contains the updated values of `x` and `y`, and one could simply pass it to the tooltip.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What GUI framework are you working with to show the tooltip?

Comment: No concrete idea but [`vsnprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) could be worth a look. This might be combined with a template which passes the appropriate number of arguments. The glibmm [`compose()`](http://manual.freeshell.org/glibmm-2.4/reference/html/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) is something else which might be worth a look. May be, you could consider to write your own `sprintf()` wrapper which splits the format string at each `%` and processes the variables in list one by one.

Comment: boost.format solves this use case nicely and is reusable.

Comment: I'm using pure Win32. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is possible, with a variadic list of arguments, pre C++11.

But starting from C++11, using variadic templates (to pass the variadic list of arguments to the constructor) and a lambda function (where you can capture the variadic list of references of arguments), you can write something as

```
class Printer
 {
   private:
      char                              buffer[1024];
      std::string                       format;
      std::function<std::string(void)>  l;

   public:
      template <typename ... Args>
      Printer (char const * f0, Args & ... as) : format{f0}
       {
         l = [&] () -> std::string
          {
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                     format.c_str(), as...);

            return buffer;
          };
       }

      std::string callback () const
       { return l(); }
 };
```

You can use `Printer` as follows

```
int main ()
 {
   int x{10}, y{20};

   Printer p{"X (%d), Y (%d)", x, y};

   x = 100;
   y = 200;

   std::cout << p.callback() << std::endl; // print X (100), Y (200)
 }
```

Observe that `x` and `y` are passed as references, not as pointers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at it when I'm home